# How to tell git to use upstream tracking for one branch but "current" behaviour for everything else?

Tags: git, push

My user-level `.gitconfig` contains:

```
[push]
default = current
```

This is the behaviour I want 99% of the time.

I have one Git checkout with two remotes, `origin` and `bitbucket`. The local `master` branch tracks `origin/master`. I also want a branch, say `bbmaster` that tracks `bitbucket/master`. So I have in `.git/config`:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

[branch "bbmaster"]
    remote = bitbucket
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Nonetheless, if I push from `bbmaster` without specifying the remote target branch:

```
$ git push
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To bitbucket.org:(remote path)
 * [new branch]      bbmaster -> bbmaster
```

...it creates a new remote branch `bbmaster`. I want it to behave as though I typed `git push -u bitbucket bbmaster:master`, but remembering to type that every time is difficult and error-prone.

I want to keep the `push.default = current` behaviour for everything else. But I want to set the occasional branch to push to a differently named branch, for this precise use case. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that for your workflow `push.default` with value `upstream` would be better.

I don't think `current` is suitable when you work with multiple *master* branches in different repos.

From [Git docos](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault):

> - `current` - push the current branch to update a branch with the same name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.
> - `upstream` - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called @{upstream}). This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. central workflow).

You could also use `nothing`

> - `nothing` - do not push anything (error out) unless a refspec is explicitly given. This is primarily meant for people who want to avoid mistakes by always being explicit.

Comment: I think this is what I need, although I'd set it for this checkout, not globally. The only drawback, minor as it is, is that it changes the default push behaviour for the whole checkout. So if there's a way to change it in an even more fine-grained way ie. per-branch, I'd prefer that.

Comment: Customizing default behavior would have led to unexpected results sooner or later (where you forget that a given branch has special setup).